# How to get slug of current category in taxonomy template?

Tags: templates, taxonomy, slug

How can I retrieve slug of current taxonomy being viewed in taxonomy template? I tried to codex but found nothing on taxonomy template page.

To further explain, lets say I am viewing category flowers so how can I retrieve slug of category flowers?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can get the term object of the category you’re viewing with `get_queried_object()`. That will contain the slug.

```
$term = get_queried_object();
echo $term->slug;
```